# detect windows jpeg icon

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

How can I detect the icon in use by  windows for jpeg pictures depending on the Windows OS version (XP,,vista,7) ? by detection I mean finding the location of it and being able of using the icon file. c++ please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find a solution for your problem here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29137/Get-Registered-File-Types-and-Their-Associated-Ico